# ASP .Net Security implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, security

I'm hoping that someone could advise if the following scenario is acceptable or not and if not what other way(s) do i have of going about this.

I have developed an ASP .Net site using Forms Authentication, using our own database (SQL) model for authentication. Multiple users can log on. One point to take into account is that **each user can NOT access each others records.**

In code what i have is on page load i have a User object which loads the details of the user logged on.

When they access a record i then have a hyperlink which has the ID of the record passed in which is the redirected to the details page where the user can view the complete record.

Now on the details page i again load the current users details and then have some SQL to **get the records by the user logged on ID AND the ID of the record passed in.**

So far this has worked as i have logged on with user 1 who accesses their own records - copy the URL and paste this inside a different browser which redirects the user to the login page. This time i log in with User 2. The page is displayed **but no details are present.**

Does this sound ok or anything else i would need to do? Of course i will implement a redirect to a Access Denied page instead of showing a blank page if no details are returned.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Please update the title with your specific problem.. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking if an already implemented mechanism is safe? If that is the question then this is not the correct site, you may want to try out on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all sounds fine - though I'd opt for something more granular: something that would allow access to other people's records on an access-control-list basis, but that's more complicated.

The only thing I'd change in what you've written is the "redirection" to an access-denied page. **Never perform redirections to error pages** - instead return the error message in the original response. You can do this in ASP.NET WebForms by using `Server.Transfer`, or by clearing the response buffer (if necessary) and setting the page content to an ASCX with the right message. Don't forget to set the HTTP status to 403.

Comment: Thanks Dai. When you say "return the error message in the original response" what do you mean? As when a user accesses another user record there are no results returned. Or do you mean if 0 records are returned then user Server.Transfer?

Comment: By "return the error message in the original response" I mean that you should return the human-readable error message to the user without performing a `Response.Redirect`, that it should be returned to the client in the same request/response cycle.

Comment: Could i just show a panel with "Access Denied" if no rows show up?